# PeerJS webRTC app not working on android 11

Tags: android, webrtc, chromium, nat, peerjs

I'm working on an audio/video call app for android. It uses PeerJS on a webView.
Here is my code for PeerJs client,

```
let localVideo = document.getElementById("local-video")
let remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remote-video")

let peer
var enableVideo
function init(userId, isVideoCall) {
    if (isVideoCall == "true") enableVideo = true
    else enableVideo = false

    peer = new Peer(userId, {
        host: '<My GCP server IP>',
        port: 9000,
        key: "myKey",
        path: '/calls',
        config: {
            'iceServers': [
                { url: 'stun:stun.ekiga.net' },
                { url: 'stun:stun.schlund.de' },
                { url: 'stun:stun.voipbuster.com' },
                { url: 'stun:stun.voipstunt.com' },
                { url: 'stun:stun.xten.com' },
                { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
                { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
                { url: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
                { url: 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302' },
                { url: 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302' },
                {
                    url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
                    username: "<myUsername>",
                    credential: '<myPassword>'
                }

            ]
        }
    })
    peer.on('open', () => {
        Android.onPeerConnected()
    })

    peer.on('error', () => {
        Android.onError()
    })
    listen()
}
let localStream;
function listen() {
    peer.on('call', (call) => {
        navigator.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: enableVideo
        }, (stream) => {
            localVideo.srcObject = stream
            localStream = stream

            call.answer(stream)
            call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
                Android.onCallConnected()
                remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream
                remoteVideo.className = "primary-video"
                localVideo.className = "secondary-video"
            })
        })
    })
}

function startCall(otherUserId) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: enableVideo
    }, (stream) => {
        localVideo.srcObject = stream
        localStream = stream

        const call = peer.call(otherUserId, stream)
        call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
            Android.onCallConnected()
            remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream
            remoteVideo.className = "primary-video"
            localVideo.className = "secondary-video"
        })
    })
}
```

Everything was working fine until I updated my phone to android 11 recently. Now the connection gets established but there is no audio or video.

It works well If we compile the app against SDK version 29. But I am targeting this app for newer versions of android.

So, if I compile for SDK version 31, then it refuses to work on the emulator(android 11) and some Samsung phones(android 11). That said, it works perfectly on some other Samsung and Realme devices running android 11.

I don’t think it’s a NAT traversal issue, because it was working fine on my Samsung phone before the android 11 update. I doubt it has something to do with android 11 webView and the chromium engine. [Checkout this link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1115498).

Can someone please help me to find a workaround for this issue?

> Update: When I check the network usage of this activity using profiler, I can see the sending and receiving rate is 0 KB/s.

Comment: I my case the issue is at navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia which is awaited & never completes whereas in your code this is rather navigator.getUserMedia

Answer (score 0):

Testing Webview when you target Android 12(SDK 31) is different than usual, either you test on Android 12 emulator or you enable the new SameSite behaviors to test with older emulators.

this is mentioned in [Behavior changes: Apps targeting Android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#samesite) on official Android developer site:

> Test SameSite behaviors in your app
> If your app uses WebView, or if you manage a website or service that uses cookies, we recommend testing your flows on Android 12 WebView. If you find issues, you might need to update your cookies to support the new SameSite behaviors.
>
> Watch for issues in logins and embedded content, as well as sign-in flows, purchasing, and other authentication flows where the user starts on an insecure page and transitions to a secure page.
>
> To test an app with WebView, you must enable the new SameSite behaviors for the app that you want to test by completing either of the following steps:
>
> 1- Manually enable SameSite behaviors on the test device by [toggling the UI flag webview-enable-modern-cookie-same-site](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/developer-ui.md#Flag-UI) in the WebView devtools.
> This approach lets you test on any device running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher—including Android 12—and WebView version 89.0.4385.0 or higher.
>
> 2- Compile your app to target Android 12 (API level 31) by targetSdkVersion.
> If you use this approach, **`you must use a device that runs Android 12.`**

Comment: Does this have anything to do with webRTC? My app doesn’t use any cookies.

Comment: To test an app with WebView, you must enable the new SameSite behaviors even if your app does not use any cookies